# Uploading files to Plunker

Tags: plunker

Is there any way to upload multiple files to http://plnkr.co, instead of copy-pasting the code all the time? Would be great if a plunker could be connected to a github repository, or if a set of files could be dragged in.

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but I suggest that you file your suggestions as an issue on the issues page on github: https://github.com/filearts/plunker_www/issues

Answer (score 19):

There is no built-in way to upload multiple files to Plunker.

Users have built tools to facilitate this. Please see: https://www.npmjs.org/package/plunk which is a command-line utility that will let you create plunks from the contents of a directory.

You can also bootstrap plunks by making `POST` requests to `http://plnkr.co/edit/` where the payload has the following format:

```
{
  "description": "Plunk description", // Optional
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", ..., "tagN"], // Optional
  "files": {
    "filename1.ext": "contents of filename1.ext",
    "filename2.ext": "and so on.."
  }
}
```

Code for this handler: https://github.com/filearts/plunker_www/blob/0c608ae80ef30d59bfdfeaf3c2a28563f7b730e4/app.coffee#L105-L121

Comment: In Plunker.NEXT you will be able to drag files or a zip into the directory tree so this will be very much simplified.

Comment: Is Plunker.Next online? With ability to drag `.zip` file into editor directory?

Comment: Any full code example of a POST to Plunker? With plain simple HTML or jQuery (for JSON)?